# Refresh credentials in Google Data Studio Community Connector

Tags: looker-studio

When an owner of a datasource logs in to connector for that datasource (user+pwd) she can use that datasource to populate reports.

When the owner changes her password on the source data platform, how can the owner then update her credentials in the connector?

I didn't find a method to refresh credentials other than revoking access to the connector entirely.

Additional question: Is there a way to create multiple instances of a connector for a data source (user+pwd) and use different credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Currently the only way to update third party credentials for a Community Connectors is to revoke access to the connector and then adding it again.
2. It isn't currently possible to have multiple instances of a Community Connector with different sets of third party credentials.